# FreeIPA - ssh as root prompted for password

Tags: ssh, security, root, freeipa

I know the access via root won't work (client sshd_config and restricted account in FreeIPA). But is there a way to blacklist root either on the host or on FreeIPA so it's denied immediately rather than prompting for a password?

I'm wondering if I'm missing something... If not possible then I guess my next goal will be to log root attempts via FreeIPA and alert/report on them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this in sshd_config:

```
Match User root
  AuthenticationMethods publickey

Match User *
  AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

Possibly add an `AuthorizedKeysFile /dev/null` to the root config as well.

Comment: can't you do `AuthenticationMethods none`

Comment: I don't think so: "none" (used for access to password-less accounts when PermitEmptyPasswords is enabled).

Comment: There's also `PermitRootLogin no` or `prohibit-password`